# How to redirect user to public/ directory in PHP Composer?

Tags: php, web, composer-php, file-structure

This is how my file structure is:

```
./ git
./ public
      ./assets/
      ./pages/
      ./index.php
./tests
./vendor
./composer.json
./composer.lock
```

**./index.php  ==> header('Location: /public/'); Should I do this ?**

Instead of typing **stories.com/public** in my browser eveytime, should I include  an index.php and then use header call or is there any other * better *  method ?

Please keep in mind I want to later on deploy my app to HEROKU for FREE

Comment: Try htaccess redirection

Comment: Don't redirect, setup your server config properly. Read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel, it has all the steps necessary to do it the right way.

Comment: I'm not using laravel

Comment: @TilakMaddy Sorry, thought I saw the tag. That said, your `public` setup is identical to Laravel's, so use the Laravel tutorial. The buildpack and config they have you use is exactly what you need.

Comment: I just saw it ! Holy shit it's too damn complicated, I think I'll never be able to learn .

Answer (score 3):

You should just set the document root folder to be your `public` folder.

This is from the FAQ: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#setting-the-document-root

> For example, if you’re using Apache with PHP, and you’d like your document root to be set to the public sub-directory of your application (because that’s where your index.php and all images, CSS and JavaScript reside), your Procfile would look like this:
>
> `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/`

Comment: There's even a Laravel-specific guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel